# Which function shall be called while doing Group by in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

When i am doing Search using Listview, search function shall be called and i have over written it to pass some extra parameters. But, while Grouping the Values how can i pass the Extra Parameters?

So, which function i have to over write to add some parameters while Grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over-write `read_group` function of `odoo/openerp` which shall be called while doing Group By and use domain parameter using which search condition shall be sent while doing grouping.